# How get ID of TeamExplorer Builds

Tags: c#, vsix

I make Hello world of VSIX extension.
I created VSIX Project and added Custom Command.

I want add this control to Team Explorer -> Build.

In TFSTreeViewPackage.vsct I have:

```
<Groups>
<Group guid="guidTFSTreeViewPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
</Group>
</Groups>
```

What id I should put, after where my control will place in build windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandExplorer) to find where existing commands are placed.
For example, how to find where Team Explorer -> Build -> Build Definition -> Add to favorite.
[image]

Use the inspect mode to find the command. once you find it, copy the guid and the id of the containing item:
[image]

If the guid synmbol and the id symbol not found, you will need to add them:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidBigBuildCmdSet" value="{34586048-8400-472e-bbbf-3ae30af8046e}">
    <IDSymbol name="menuBuildsPageDefinition" value="0x109" />
</GuidSymbol>
```

And change your group to:

```
<Groups>
    <Group guid="guidTFSTreeViewPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidBigBuildCmdSet" id="menuBuildsPageDefinition"/>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```